# Concat sequential 2 elements of an array as an array in new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapreduce

Suppose if we have an array [1,2,3,4,5,6], i want to get a new array [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]. I don't want to use for loop.I want to solve it using map-reduce or using best practice but I am not getting how to use map-reduce. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder) `%` for checking. If zero, push to the last inserted array otherwise to result with a new array.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        i % 2 ? r[r.length - 1].push(a) : r.push([a]);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Nina, please tell how to get command on map-reduce, Yesterday also you saved me. I don't want to ask these basic question again and again. Please suggest me some good documents.

Comment: i have no documents, the answer is straight, jut look what the modulo operator is doing and have a look to the different inserted values.

Comment: Hi Nina, Please help me out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40447041/stream-the-contents-of-each-file-using-web-sockets-and-reactjs

Answer (score 0):

You could use a temporary object, but I don't think reduce is ment for this purpose. IMHO I'd use a for loop.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].reduce(
  function(a,b) { 
    if(a.val) {
      a.arr.push([a.val, b]);
      a.val = false;
    } else {
      a.val = b;
    } return a; 
  }, {
    arr: [],
    val: false
  }
).arr
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.of()`, `Array.prototype.slice()`

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var res = Array.of(arr.slice(0,2), arr.slice(2,4), arr.slice(4));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a recursive function. It also takes into account the case of arrays with odd length.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

function div(arr) {
  return arr.length <= 1 ? [arr] : [[arr[0], arr[1]]].concat(div(arr.slice(2)));
}

console.log(div(a));
```